# Selecting two certain rows from a result table?

Tags: mysql, filtering

If my result rows are as follow:

```
ID    Name     Rate_Type
1     xxxx         9
2     zzzz         22
3     cccc         12
4     eeee         17
5     uuuu         90
```

Now how can I select the row with the rate type = 9 and any other row. I want my query to tell me if there is a row with Rate_type 9 and to give me also one row with ID <> 9

I want to have this result (only two row result):

```
ID    Name     Rate_Type
1     xxxx         9
!     !!!!         !--> This should be one additional row with Rate_Type <>9
```

Comment: Read This https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `union` of two queries. One that gets your `rate_type = 9`, and one that gets your `rate_type <> 9`

```
(select * from t where rate_type = 9 order by rand() limit 1) 
union all
(select * from t where rate_type <> 9 order by rand() limit 1);
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba1e4/8)

Comment: This was my solution :), but i though there is a better way. since my query is really huge. but thanks for your answer :)

Comment: then you should have put this in the question and asked for an alternative :)  this strikes me as the easiest solution however -- downside with (this) version being `order by rand()` could be a performance killer.  If you don't care if you always get the same results, remove that part of it